# file path serving on a sub domain fed from main domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, cross-domain

I have a few sub-domains that use that main domain as a repository.

maindomain.com
 - site1.maindomain.com
 - site2.maindomain.com
 - site3.maindomain.com
Each site has the same design, but each subdomain runs from a different database.

in each sub domain i have an index.php and also a config.php file. The config sets up the db connection for that site and also things like site name, main domain address etc. The index.php calls the includes from the main domain.

I have set a var to prefix all server side addresses from '/home/public_html' and all http requests for 'maindomain.com/'
The problem is when using ajax queries it is trying to call the file from the subdomain. Using the server side var doesn't work as the root is always site1.mydomain.com. Using the http request var and i get an error message:

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.maindomain.com/login.php. Origin http://site1.maindomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Now i guess this is due to web server restrictions to control cross-domain file access, but being as it's a subdomain there must be a way around it?

Any help would be appreciated!
K

Comment: weird!!! it should allow to make request if you are under top level domain, as your all second level domains are in same domain CORS is not an issue. It must be something with different locations of config file.

Comment: yeah i expected it to work too - kinda buggered up my repository ideas until it can be sorted - might fire an email to the hosting co and see if they can see why!

Comment: solved! 
Adding 
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
to the top of the php file being called resolved the issue! :)